# Angular partials can't use HTML5 File Reader

Tags: html, angularjs

I see that my Angular partials cannot detect or use the HTML FileReader API.  Can someone explain this and does it apply to other HTML5 features?

Comment: <script>
    if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") console.log("ok");
    </script>

Comment: Did you try it on just a regular html page?  It might just be the browser in use, as opposed to Angular.  See http://caniuse.com/filereader for browser support.

Comment: It works fine with my Firefox browswer on any regular html page, including the main index page of the Angular app. Now I can see that even <script>alert("hello");</script> won't execute on an Angular partial. So the question is can you run ANY javascript in a partial.